# http.getの結果を格納した配列の内容がundefinedになる

Tags: javascript, axios

APIを叩いて取得した値を配列に入れて、任意のタイミングで取り出したいです。

```
const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'base-url',
})

var a = []

function addArray () {
  http.get('/hoge/fuga', { data: {} }).then(response => {
    a.push(response.data.name)
  })
}

Array.from({ length: 30 }).map(() => {
    addArray()
    console.log(a[0])
  })
```

一部ソースコードを省略していますが、`console.log(a[0])`とすると`undefined`となってしまします。

`console.log(a)`だけで出力すると下記のようになり、index:0で取得できそうなのですが、取得できません。

```
[]
    0: '名前'
    length: 0
    __proto: Array(0)
        concat: f concat()
        長いので省略します
```

取得できない原因は何でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

取得できないのではないと思います。

`console.log(a[0])` を実行したタイミングでは

```
.then(response => {
    a.push(response.data.name)
})
```

のコールバックが呼ばれておらず、まだ値が設定されていないだけではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。`axios`を使用しているので、非同期処理のために値が設定されていないということになりそうですね。非同期処理に不慣れで、どう実装してよいものかわからないので、学ぼうと思います。